# R: matrix  operation[new version]

Tags: r, matrix

I need work on a n x n type of matrix ( n > 100 usually), a small example is as follows:

```
    mymat <- as.matrix(cbind(V1 = c(11, 12, 13, 14),V2 = c(21, 22, 23, 24),
           V3 = c( 31, 32, 33, 34), V4 = c(41, 42, 43, 44) ) )
    row.names (mymat) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

   V1 V2 V3 V4
a 11 21 31 41
b 12 22 32 42
c 13 23 33 43
d 14 24 34 44
```

I need to work on elements (means matrix element (2,1) and (1,2) or (3,4) and (4,3) and so on:

```
 mymat[1,2] * ( mymat[1,2] +  mymat[2,1]) = 12 * (12 + 21) = 396
```

The complete operation will include Yij (Yij + Yji), for elements that are in diagonal of the matrix it would be:

```
mymat[2,2] * (mymat[2,2] + mymat[2,2]) = 22 * (22 + 22) = 968
```

Thus complete operation will be:

```
   11 * (11 + 11) + 12 * (12 + 21) + 13 * (13 + 31) + 14 * (14 + 41) + 
 21 * (21 * 12)  + 22 * (22 + 22) + 23 * (23 + 32) + 24 * ( 24 + 42) + 
 31 * ( 13 + 31) + 32 * (23 + 32) + 33 * ( 33 + 33) + 34 * (34 + 43) + 
 44 * (44 + 44) =  22881
```

Sorry I could not figure out, need your help.

Comment: This is real problem, I can rewrite it to make it more clear. I should apologize not have strong matrix operation knowledge...

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to take the reciprocal of?  I have no idea what you're trying to do.  Please give sample output to go with your sample input.

Comment: please see my revised version

Comment: Again, what quantity are you trying to take the reciprocal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) of?

Comment: John, you have described the operations to be done.  What quantity is unknown?  Or, as @JackManey has asked, what do you mean by inverse?  There's nothing here that involves inversion.

Comment: I could find proper term to define elements of matrix such as [2,1], [1,2] ...I deleted term "reciprocal" to avoid the calculation.... sorry no reciprocal mathematics is involved here...

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It seems like a nested for loop would be an ok way to make a first stab at this.  Have you tried that?  What is the context of this problem?

Comment: @John You have an error in the second row: `21 * (21 * 12)` seems like it should be `21 * (21 + 12)`.

Comment: @Iterator: No argument there!  But seems like he's written it out in a loop format anyway so the easy fix would be for him to think in terms of i's and j's.

Comment: And it seems that your other entries for the 4th column are all missing, i.e. there is no coefficient for 41, 42, 43. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
myMatrix = mymat
myProductSum = myMatrix * (myMatrix + t(myMatrix))
myTotal = sum(myProductSum)
```

These do the calculations you've outlined, namely element-wise summation, followed by element-wise products, and then a summation of the entire matrix.

If, for some reason, you want to do something different for diagonal elements, you could adapt the following:

```
myDiag = diag(diag(mymat))
myMatrix = mymat - myDiag
myProductSum = myMatrix * (myMatrix + t(myMatrix))
myTotal = sum(myProductSum) + sum(2 * myDiag^2)
```

Comment: reciprocal is deleted to avoid confusion ..

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that.  :)

Comment: I think that the calculation now performs as requested, but I wonder if there are errors in your example.